# Vue.js DOM not updating (integrating a Symfony form with dynamic content)

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I made a dynamic `vue component` that loads a whole form generated backend with `Symfony/Twig`. This works fine with simple forms.

Now, I'm trying to make it work with *dynamic fields* (let say country/city) : when you choose a ***country*** in one of the form's input an ajax call update the choices in the ***cities***' input.

I'm stuck on the very last step. I get my updated field's html, I replace the ***cities*** input with this new object, **but the change doesn't show up in the DOM**.

Below's my component's code. In the `initializeDynamicFields()` method (at the bottom of the code), upon success of an `ajax` call, I make the replacement that does not update the DOM as I hope it would. `dynamicFieldParent` and `dynamicFieldChild` are the ids of the form's dynamic fields.

I'm calling this method in both `mounted()` and `updated()`.

> EDIT Problem solved : I was calling a component's prop inside the ajax callback instead of storing its a content into a variable beforehand.

```
<template>
    <div class="card bg-light border-dark">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 v-if="title" class="card-title">{{ title }}</h3>
            <div v-html="content" v-on:click.capture="handleClick"></div>
            <!--<div ref="body" v-on:click.capture="handleClick"></div>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
    var formSerialize = require('form-serialize');
    export default {
        name: "dynamic-form",
        props: ['url', 'dynamicFieldParent', 'dynamicFieldChild'],
        data() {
            return {
                title: '',
                content: '',
                components: null
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.load(this.url);
        },
        mounted() {
            if (this.dynamicFieldParent) {
                this.initializeDynamicFields();
            }
        },
        updated() {
            if (this.dynamicFieldParent) {
                this.initializeDynamicFields();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            load(url) {
                axios.get(url, {
                    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
                }).then(response => {
                    this.title = response.data.title;
                    this.content = response.data.content;
                    this.components = response.data.components;
                });
            },

            handleClick(e) {
                if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON' && e.target.type == 'submit' && e.target.form.checkValidity()) {
                    this.submit(e);
                }
            },

            submit(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.$root.$emit('form-sending');
                let data = formSerialize(e.target.form, {
                    hash: false, empty: true
                });
                data += '&' + e.target.name + '=' 
                        + encodeURIComponent(e.target.value);
                axios.post(this.url, data, {
                    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
                }).then(response => {
                    this.title = response.data.title;
                    this.content = response.data.content;
                    this.components = response.data.components;
                    if (response.status == 201) {
                        this.$root.$emit('form-success');
                    }
                });
            },

            initializeDynamicFields() {
                var $parent = $('#' + this.dynamicFieldParent);
                var $child = $('#' + this.dynamicFieldChild);
                $parent.change(function() {
                    var $form = $parent.closest('form');
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.set($parent.attr('name'), $parent.val());
                    axios.post($form.attr('action'), formData).then(response => {
                        $child.replaceWith(
                            response.data.content.find('#' + this.dynamicFieldChild)
                        );

                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html:

**Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates**

In other words, since you're using `v-html` to load your backend generated form, it's not used as a Vue template, it's just pasted in as plain HTML, which means it won't be able to bind to values and update things in the way you normally would in a Vue app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this is not the recommended "Vue way", but do you know  how I could force the refresh of the DOM ?

Comment: `$forceUpdate()` is a function to force update the Vue DOM, but again `v-html` doesn't bind things to Vue. I think you would need to look into using `Vue.compile("template as string")` https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile